# Mapping of a geo_point field in ElasticSearch with Tire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, elasticsearch, tire

I'm trying to index a geo_point field in Elasticsearch with the Tire gem. Here is my Tire mapping for my ActiveRecord model :

```
class Availability < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :date, :latitude, :longitude

  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  tire do
    mapping do
      indexes :id,                  type: 'integer',  index: 'not_analysed'
      indexes :user_id,                 type: 'integer',  index: 'not_analysed'
      indexes :user_firstname,      type: 'string',   as: 'user_firstname' 
      indexes :user_lastname,       type: 'string',   as: 'user_lastname' 
      indexes :user_level,          type: 'integer',  as: 'user_level' 
      indexes :date,                type: 'date'
      indexes :location,            type: 'geo_type', as: 'location'
    end
  end

  # def location
  #   "#{latitude},#{longitude}"
  # end

  def location
    [longitude.to_f, latitude.to_f]
  end

  def user_firstname
    user.firstname
  end

  def user_lastname
    user.lastname
  end

  def user_level
    user.level
  end
end
```

When I create the mapping (`bundle exec rake environment tire:import CLASS=Availability FORCE=true`), Elasticsearch seems to ignore the `geo_point` type for the `location` field.

Here is the result of the `http://localhost:9200/availabilities/_mapping` call :

```
{
  availabilities: {
    availability: {
      properties: {
        date: {...},
        id: {...},
        location: {
          type: "double"
        },
        user_firstname: {...},
        user_id: {...},
        user_lastname: {...},
        user_level: {...}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The location field is indexed as an array of double on the documents (results of `http://localhost:9200/availabilities/_search`) :

```
{
  id: 8,
  ...
  location: [
    2.301643,
    48.780651
  ]
}
```

When I change the `location` method to :

```
  def location
    "#{latitude},#{longitude}"
  end
```

Which is another solution to index a `geo_point` field according to the documentation (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/geo-point-type.html), the result for the location mapping is :

```
  location: {
    type: "string"
  },
```

And of course the location field is indexed as a string :

```
{
  id: 4,
  ...
  location: "48.780651,2.301643"
}
```

Any idea why the `geo_point` is ignored in my mapping ?

Thanks !

Comment: This is weird: could you generate a blank Tire app (see command in the README) with location support? I have tried, and the mapping is correctly stored. Also, could you try to use the version from Github in your Gemfile?

Comment: Arrgh !!! I mistyped the type ! It's not geo_type but geo_point... Weirdly I had no error from elasticsearch, but after an update (to 0.19.10), elasticsearch dumped an error... Thanks for the help and sorry for this "typo question" :)

Comment: Cool! Glad it has been solved.

Comment: Maybe add your solution as an answer, so the question is correctly tagged as "answered" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `location` index type was mistyped.

You used `geo_type` instead of `geo_point`:

```
indexes :location, type: 'geo_point', as: 'location'
```